# RabbitMQ Cluster with Load Balancer

Tags: php, rabbitmq, load-balancing, high-availability

I need to sync tables between different databases. Therefore I want to setup a high availability RabbitMQ cluster. It's really important that no message get lost because it would result in an async table.

[image: RabbitMQ Cluster with LB]

As you can see here, this approach has a critical point of failure. If the load balancer isn't reachable for whatever reason the sender isn't able to send messages to the RabbitMQ queue.

Possible options would be:

1. Add all the nodes to your application and loop through them until you found a working one.
2. Install a software load balancer like HAProxy on all your webserver nodes to resolve to a working RabbitMQ node.

I didn't feel comfortable with both solutions. Maybe someone has a better idea or has some further reading for this specific topic?

I want to use RabbitMQ with php. Shouldn't be important to know for this question but maybe someone knows a PHP specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem.

If the load-balancer can `fail` in your scenario, you have to implement the `HA` behavior to the client side.

Most of RabbitMQ clients doesn't implement the `HA`. 
For example this [client](https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra) implements the `HA` client side.

If you are afraid about the load-balancer fail, you could also configure the load-balancer in `HA`   .

I'd put the attention to configure the load-balancer in `HA`.

BTW your question is quite generic, hope it helps